# Do empty properties take up bandwidth when sending a class over WCF?

Tags: c#, wcf

We want to send two collections of objects out of a WCF service. The classes for the two objects share some common properties, and each have others, unique to them...

```
public class TypeA {
  public string A { get; set; }
  public string B { get; set; }
  public string C { get; set; }
  public string D { get; set; }
}

public class TypeB {
  public string A { get; set; }
  public string B { get; set; }
  public string E { get; set; }
  public string F { get; set; }
}
```

> Yes I could/should use a common base class, but that isn't the question here

One the one hand, having two classes like this means that each class only has the properties it needs, which keeps it slim and focused. On the other hand, as these are basically two different views of the same underlying object, it's perfectly reasonable to combine them, and just populate the properties needed.

I can't find a way of seeing how big the WCF payload is, so don't know if using one common class is going to consume more bandwidth than using specific classes. I need this to be as efficient as possible.

Anyone know if using one common class is going to increase the WCF payload? If so, any way of find out how much?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the `XmlSerializerFormat` attribute on your services in order to force WCF to use ASP.NET serialization engine when sending your objects.  This will allow you to use other attributes and methods to take full control over which properties are serialized.

Then, you can restrict properties from being serialized using two methods:
1. Implement a ShouldSerializeXXXX() method
2. Use the DefaultValue attribute.  Properties which already have the default value are not serialized.

Example:

```
[XmlSerializerFormat, ServiceContract]
public interface IMyService
{
    [OperationContract]
    MyData GetData();
}

[DataContract]
public class MyData
{
    [XmlAttribute, DataMember]
    public int Value1 { get; set; }

    // Explicit method to control serialization of Value1 property
    public bool ShouldSerializeValue1()
    {
        // do not serialize this value if it's 0
        return Value1 != 0;
    }

    // Use default value of 0 to prevent serializing zeros
    [XmlAttribute, DataMember, DefaultValue(0)]
    public int Value2 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I created a test WCF service, and used a class that had some int and string properties. I added a service method that returned 100 new instances of the class (no properties set), and Fiddler showed the total response bytes as 14,444 bytes. I then added the attributes you showed to the properties, using DefaultValue(0) for the ints and DefaultValue(null) for the strings. Fiddler showed exactly the same number of response bytes. I tried changing it to DefaultValue("") for the strings to see if that made any difference, but it didn't. Any ideas?

Comment: @AvrohomYisroel I made a mistake in my example above and it has been corrected now.  The XmlSerializerFormat attribute should be applied to your service and/or methods rather than the object that gets returned.

Comment: Ah, that made a big difference! The payload went down from 14,444 bytes to 1,308! I imagine on a real scenario, it would be an even bigger difference.

Answer (score 1):

I would be more concerned with the data transfer type you are using if you are worried about packet size. For example, if you are using the SOAP protocol, then your packet size is going to be very large and instead of worrying about base classes to objects, you could shrink down your packet size tremendously by switching to binary, or even JSON. See here for reference: https://dzone.com/articles/wcf-rest-xml-json-or-both

Also, to inspect true packet size I would install 'fiddler' on your machine and inspect the data as it goes over the network.

I hope that sets you on the correct path...

Comment: Thanks, but we are already using binary, which did help, but I'm looking to squeeze even more out of it, and was looking to see if this would help. Thanks for the tip about Fiddler, I'll take a look.